# shell scripting export file

Tags: shell-script

I have output that I need to export to a file. Then I need to call this file to run the script in it. Another condition would be to run the last query or instruction after 15mins. See code below:

```
#SORT RESULT IN DESCENDING ORDER. 
#FORMAT SYNTAX FOR BACKUP DELETION
sort -r ${TEMPRESULT2} | sed -e "s/^/DELETE BACKUP /g" | sed -e "s/$/ NOWARNING/g"
```

output:

```
DELETE BACKUP (backupid) NOWARNING

DELETE BACKUP (backupid) NOWARNING
```

[pause then run after 15mins]

```
DELETE BACKUP (finalbackupid) NOWARNING
```

the final backup id can only run once all other backupids are done

Comment: Your output files do not contain valid bash syntax, but something like SQL statements. I guess with 'running' you mean something like `mysql < outputfile.sql` or something? Could you add these details?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different sequence of command to be executed at two different times. The most logical solution would therefore be to put these command in two different files:

```
TEMPRESULT3=$(sort -r ${TEMPRESULT2} | sed -e "s/^/DELETE BACKUP /g" | sed -e "s/$/ NOWARNING/g")

# Put all lines except the last one in a first script:
echo "$TEMPRESULT3" | head -n -1 >"path/to/first-script"

# Put the last line in a second script:
echo "$TEMPRESULT3" | tail -n 1 >"path/to/second-script"
```

As far as I know negative line number is an extension of GNU `head`, if it is not available you must calculate the number of lines before executing it (`total=$(echo "$TEMPRESULT3" | wc -l); all_but_least=$(expr $total - 1)`, then `$all_but_least` cna be passed as parameter to the first `head` command instead of `-1`).

After that, all you have to do is call these script the way you want. For instance, if I take the `mysql` syntax proposed by Benjamin B. it would be:

```
mysql < "path/to/first-script"
# 800 s. = 15 m.
sleep 800
mysql < "path/to/second-script"
```

Comment: This won't work because `$TEMPRESULT3` holds a single line, all lines joined with a space.  You'll need temporary `IFS` modification.

Comment: @yaegashi: Did you tried this? What you say is true for `echo $TEMPRESULT3` (without quotes, where each word composing `$TEMPRESULT3` are considered as separate arguments for `echo` so spaces and line feeds are not preserved), not for `echo "$TEMPRESULT3"` (with double-quotes, where `echo` receives a single argument which is `$TEMPRESULT3` actual value, multiple spaces and line feeds being preserved).

Comment: Confirmed, you're right.  In my tests I've dropped quotes and seen the result of `IFS= && echo $TEMPRESULT3`.  Sorry for the noise...

Comment: @yaegashi: No problem, it is useful to highlight such details which may be easily be missed by other readers :)

Answer (score 1):

You can write the output into a file an execute it as shell program like below:

```
sort -r ${TEMPRESULT2} | sed -e "s/^/DELETE BACKUP /g" | sed -e "s/$/ NOWARNING/g" > file.sh && chmod +x file.sh && sleep 15m && ./file.sh
```

Comment: How do you pause for 15 min. before running the last line?

Comment: If you want to pause the script, you should use the sleep unix command, I just updated the script

Comment: If you call two times the same script, it will just execute two times all the commands therein.

Comment: thanks for the responses! i separated the 1st set of backups then the last full backup so there's no conflict with the pause... ^_^